# How to use GetProcAddress dynamically

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, dll

As we know, we could use GetProcAddress to get a function pointer from a DLL handle such as for method foo defined at a DLL:

```
int foo(long)
```

we could get the function pointer like this for foo function:

```
typedef int(* FOO_FUNC)(long)
FOO_FUNC pFooFunc = (FOO_FUNC) GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "foo")
```

However we are thinking if we could make it dynamic further, let's say, I know that I have a list of input argument and their type which is correct for current method and I would like to call this method on a dll and then get a list of output argument (with their type as well)

```
//VARIANT would be able to hold different type of data with different type
std::vector<VARIANT> inputArguments;
std::string methodName = "foo"
void * pFunc = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, methodName.c_str())
std::vector<VARIANT> outputArguments;
callMethodDynamically(pFunc, inputArgument, &outputArguments)
```

Is it possible to implement the above callMethodDynamically at C/C++? The only way I could think of is that we would have to push the argument to stack and then call the pFunc. I guess then it would be assembly language. Is there any other ways here? We would have to handle different call convention here as well (stdcall, cdecl).

Comment: For some calling conventions, you'll need an assembly thunk.  For example, on x64 there is only one calling convention, and it is a fastcall convention, so you have to be able to enregister arguments.  You can fake most x86 stdcall functions in pure C++ with some ugly casts.

Comment: As another alternative, have you considered using COM (or XPCOM)? Because you're largely trying to duplicate what it was designed for. Unless you're trying to do this on arbitrary DLLs not written to be accessed in this way, which which case… where do you get the information about what the actual types in inputArguments and outputArguments are?

Comment: This describes the IDispatch interface.  Which does *not* use GetProcAddress(), it uses DllGetClassObject()

Comment: The C/C++ language is not powerful enough to call functions whose prototypes are not known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the response.  Basically our solution has C++ core engine and a Lua script engine. The DLL method would be called by the Lua script which knows the exact method signature. However it needs to call the DLL method through core engine where it doesn't know each method signature. Since the DLL is written by us, the DLL could just expose an Invoke method which would take VARIANT type of input and return VARIANT type of output similar to IDispatch.Invoke. Inside the Invoke method, it would dispatch to specific method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a wrapper function for each real function.

e.g.

```
int addNumbers( int x, int y ) { return x + y; }

void addNumbersW( std::vector<VARIANT>& inArgs, std::vector<VARIANT>& outArgs )
{
    // decode in args somehow
    int x = getArg( inArgs, 0 );
    int y = getArg( inArgs, 1 );
    int r = addNumbers( x, y );
    addArg( outArgs, r );
}
```

You could probably write a series of wrapper functions for each function prototype and simplify usage with some macros.

Comment: thanks. My thought is very similar to what you have here. I think we could just write one generic function which would take the function name as one of argument. The generic function would internally switch on the function name to call the correct internal function.